# Scrapy is not working when go to child pages

Tags: python, scrapy

I want to get some information inside each child page, this goes.
However the code does not enter the child page and goes to the next page.
What should be done is to take the data inside the child page and go to the bottom element to the end of the page and then change the page.

```
import scrapy
from ukparl.items import UkparlItem


class UkparlSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'ukparldata'

    # allowed_domains = ["https://members.parliament.uk/"]
    start_urls = ['https://members.parliament.uk/members/commons?page=1']

    def parse(self, response):

        nextpageurl = response.xpath('//a[@title="Go to next page"]/@href')

        yield from self.scrape(response)

        if nextpageurl:
            path = nextpageurl.extract_first()
            nextpage = response.urljoin(path)
            print("Found url: {}".format(nextpage))
            yield scrapy.Request(nextpage, callback=self.parse)

    def scrape(self, response):
        for resource in response.xpath('//div[@class="primary-info"]/..'):
            item = UkparlItem()

            item['name'] = resource.xpath('div[@class="primary-info"]/text()').extract_first()

            profilepage = response.urljoin(resource.xpath('//a[@class="card card-member"]/@href').extract_first())
            item['link'] = profilepage
            item['party'] = resource.xpath('div[@class="secondary-info"]/text()').extract_first()
            item['region'] = resource.xpath('//div[@class="indicator indicator-label"]/text()').extract_first()

            request = scrapy.Request(profilepage, callback=self.get_data)
            request.meta['item'] = item
            yield request
                
    def get_data(self, response):
        item = response.meta['item']
        item['phonenumber'] = response.xpath('//div[@class="contact-line"]/a/text()').extract_first()
        item['twitter'] = response.xpath('//a[@class="card card-contact-info"][2]/@href').extract()
        yield item
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It does enter the 'child page', you can add print(item) in 'get_data' function to see it.

The problem is that you scrape the same page over and over:

```
<GET https://members.parliament.uk/members/commons?page=2> (referer: https://members.parliament.uk/members/commons?page=1)
<GET https://members.parliament.uk/member/4362/contact>
<GET https://members.parliament.uk/member/4362/contact>
<GET https://members.parliament.uk/member/4362/contact>
<GET https://members.parliament.uk/member/4362/contact>
<GET https://members.parliament.uk/member/4362/contact>
<GET https://members.parliament.uk/member/4362/contact>
<GET https://members.parliament.uk/member/4362/contact>
<GET https://members.parliament.uk/member/4362/contact>
<GET https://members.parliament.uk/member/4362/contact>
And so on
```

You can change:

```
profilepage = response.urljoin(resource.xpath('//a[@class="card card-member"]/@href').extract_first())

to

profilepage = response.urljoin(resource.xpath('../../@href').extract_first())

(I think it's better to replace response.xpath('//div[@class="primary-info"]/..') with something else but it's just my opinion)
```

as you can see it works:

```
DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://members.parliament.uk/member/3922/contact> (referer: https://members.parliament.uk/members/commons?page=5)
<GET https://members.parliament.uk/member/3986/contact>
<GET https://members.parliament.uk/member/4769/contact>
<GET https://members.parliament.uk/member/1538/contact>
<GET https://members.parliament.uk/member/420/contact>
<GET https://members.parliament.uk/member/185/contact>
<GET https://members.parliament.uk/member/4439/contact>
<GET https://members.parliament.uk/member/4589/contact>
<GET https://members.parliament.uk/member/4806/contact>
<GET https://members.parliament.uk/member/4465/contact>
<GET https://members.parliament.uk/member/1508/contact>
<GET https://members.parliament.uk/member/4368/contact>
<GET https://members.parliament.uk/member/1554/contact>
<GET https://members.parliament.uk/member/4469/contact>
<GET https://members.parliament.uk/member/4088/contact>
<GET https://members.parliament.uk/member/4859/contact>
<GET https://members.parliament.uk/member/3950/contact>
<GET https://members.parliament.uk/member/1406/contact>
```

Comment: Its worked.
Thank you very much for you help, i was crazy trying to make it work and was a detail.

Comment: I used this part  ->  "response.xpath('//div[@class="primary-info"]/..')" , because the 'FOR LOP'. Could i make this parte different?

Comment: @conradobio for the for loop you can use response.xpath(//a[contains(@class,"card card-member")]') and for the profile page just get the url attribute '@href' (I you don't succeed in doing this update and I will help). Please don't forget to accept the answer.